# "This app is preventing you from restarting" (app name in random Chinese characters)

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

[image: closing 1 app and restarting]

Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this? Virus? Hard drive corruption? This was just prior to a shutdown in Windows 10 and was a little alarming. Apparently the Chinese has no legible meaning either.

Comment: Yes it's likely malicious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Chinese" is the result of a badly written program trying to pass ASCII-superset data, usually Windows-125x (aka 'ANSI') or UTF-8, to a function that expects UTF-16. Most combinations of two ASCII bytes, when [misinterpreted as UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), map to places in the Unicode ["CJK"](https://codepoints.net/search?blk=CJK) block.

For example, `f` `i` (bytes 0x69 0x66) in ASCII → `楦` (codepoint U+6966) in UTF-16LE.

Your program's title is actually something like:

```
$ echo 膊獵整枋潎楴楦慣楴湯牁慥獍箌硯 | iconv -t utf-16le
��uste�gNotificationAreaMs�{ox
```

(There's some garbage in the output because Google Translate's OCR didn't correctly recognize all characters in the screenshot. You'd have more luck with larger font-size or DPI settings, or if you could just copy & paste the title directly.)

Comment: Further reading: [Why does misdetected Unicode text tend to show up as Chinese characters?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953)

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you for all this feedback and the fantastic answer